# How do I correctly pass query parameters through shell_exec in php

Tags: php, shell-exec

I have this statement in a php script:

```
shell_exec("curl https://$domain/$url.php?importid=$importid&org=$org&t=".urlencode($t)." >> /var/log/bgrd_call.log 2>&1 ");
```

The nginx/access.log file shows it correctly substitutes all variables with runtime values.
However, it only passes the first query parameter and truncates the rest of the line. I know this because whenever I re-arrange the query parameters, the first one shows up in the access.log entry.

First assigning the parameter to a variable and echoing out results in this (cutting off the url portion):

```
accept_orders.php?importid=268&org=4&t=2023-06-12+14%3A26%3A43 >> /var/log/bgrd_call.log 2>&1
```

Corresponding access.log entry:

```
[12/Jun/2023:13:30:04 +0000] "GET /accept_orders.php?importid=268 HTTP/1.1" 200 3943 "-" "curl/7.81.0"
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Can you share sample input that triggers the problem?

Comment: Perhaps wrap your full URL in `escapeshellarg()`

Comment: To troubleshoot I had also first assigned to a variable and echoed out. Here's the portion that doesn't show my URL:  accept_orders.php?importid=268&org=4&t=2023-06-12+14%3A26%3A43 >> /var/log/bgrd_call.log 2>&1

Comment: Corresponding access.log entry:    [12/Jun/2023:13:30:04 +0000] "GET /accept_orders.php?importid=268 HTTP/1.1" 200 3943 "-" "curl/7.81.0"

Comment: Please add **all** clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section

Comment: Would it work to use quotes around the whole URL?

Comment: @RobEyre - has the right answer.  However, this is not a good way to pass information.  It would be better if you used the SESSION variable.

Comment: @RohitGupta can  you share more details about this? How would you store the data in the sesssion of a remote server without sending it? Also, keep in mind that adding the session cookie to cURL might not be that simple

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are encountering is likely because of the `&` character, which has a special meaning on the shell command line.

I suggest wrapping your full URL in `escapeshellarg()` like so:

```
$url = "https://$domain/$url.php?importid=$importid&org=$org&t=".urlencode($t);
shell_exec("curl " . escapeshellarg($url) . " >> /var/log/bgrd_call.log 2>&1");
```

Comment: With this, no errors in error.log yet the call no longer shows up in access.log and its not being executed in the background.  Contents of $url seems ok when echoed out viz: accept_orders.php?importid=268&org=4&t=2023-06-12+15%3A28%3A38

Comment: Very strange, this didn't work until I changed ">> /var/log/bgrd_call.log  2>&1" to "> /dev/null 2>&1 &". Not sure why.